# Why do all my items go to unordered_map bucket 0?

Tags: c++, hashmap

This is the log (truncated) from my analysis of the hashmap:

```cpp
unsigned nbuckets = octree->Nodes.bucket_count();

LOG(Error, "bucket size = {0}, kk = {1}", nbuckets, octree->Nodes.max_load_factor());

for (auto& x : octree->Nodes) {
   LOG(Warning, "Element [{0}:{1}] is in bucket {2}", x.first.morton, x.second.position, octree->Nodes.bucket(x.first));
}
```

```
[ 00:19:26.169 ]: [Error] bucket size = 512, kk = 1.0
[ 00:19:26.169 ]: [Warning] Element [132120576:X:384 Y:384 Z:384] is in bucket 0
[ 00:19:26.169 ]: [Warning] Element [115343360:X:128 Y:384 Z:384] is in bucket 0
[ 00:19:26.169 ]: [Warning] Element [98566144:X:384 Y:128 Z:384] is in bucket 0
[ 00:19:26.169 ]: [Warning] Element [81788928:X:128 Y:128 Z:384] is in bucket 0
[ 00:19:26.169 ]: [Warning] Element [65011712:X:384 Y:384 Z:128] is in bucket 0
[ 00:19:26.169 ]: [Warning] Element [48234496:X:128 Y:384 Z:128] is in bucket 0
[ 00:19:26.169 ]: [Warning] Element [31457280:X:384 Y:128 Z:128] is in bucket 0
[ 00:19:26.169 ]: [Warning] Element [16515072:X:192 Y:192 Z:192] is in bucket 0
[ 00:19:26.169 ]: [Warning] Element [14417920:X:64 Y:192 Z:192] is in bucket 0
[ 00:19:26.169 ]: [Warning] Element [12320768:X:192 Y:64 Z:192] is in bucket 
....
```

Map is defined like this:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<Int3Pos, OctreeNode, Int3Pos::HashFunction> Nodes;
```

where OctreeNode is a struct with some values. And Int3Pos:

```cpp
struct Int3Pos // TODO rename
{
public:
    Int3_64 position;
    uint64 morton;

    Int3Pos() : position(Int3_64(0, 0, 0)), morton(0) { }
    Int3Pos(Int3_64 c)
    {
        this->position = c;
        this->morton = mrtn(this->position);
    }

    bool operator==(const Int3Pos& otherPos) const
    {
        if (this->morton == otherPos.morton) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    struct HashFunction
    {
        size_t operator()(const Int3Pos& pos) const
        {
            return pos.morton;
        }
    };
};
```

It tells 512 buckets, but all go to 0. Or I am misinterpreting something?

Comment: Probably your hash function always returns the same value for every object. Are you sure `morton` is different for each object? Otherwise, you should post a [MCVE].

Comment: `if(condition) return true; else return false;` can just be `return condition;`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes you can see in LOG the different integers. I am sure. I added the log printing code.

Comment: What is `nbuckets`? Does it have some relation to `Nodes`?

Comment: If were to guess the bug is in whatever `mrtn()` does to initialize a morton.

Comment: @drescherjm They added the code that performs the logging and it shows that they print the value of `morton` for each key object in the map, and they are all different.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you solve your problem. The behavior shown is strange. You'll need to share a [MCVE] to provide more information.

Comment: @NathanPierson updated the code, sorry

Comment: @drescherjm works fine, as can be seen in log

Comment: @François Andrieux I can't. I tried to make min example. And it works fine.

Comment: I would set a breakpoint on `return pos.morton;` and inspect what happens in  your debugger.

Comment: @drescherjm just did, all fine. The expected number is returned. Mystery :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your hash function is very bad. The greatest common divisor of the morton values you shown is

GCD(132120576, 115343360, 98566144, 81788928, 65011712, 48234496, 31457280, 16515072, 14417920, 12320768) = 2^18 = 262144

It is divided by 512. All values go to the (first) bucket 0.

You can try

```
return pos.morton % 511;  // or pos.morton % 1023, or std::hash<decltype(pos.morton)>{}(pos.morton).
```

Comment: What is divided by 512 and how does it make go to 0 bucket?

Comment: All shown hash values are divided by the number of buckets 512. You want learn how hash maps are implemented, how buckets are chosen.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you use MSVC implementation, which uses power of two sizes of `unordered_map`.  Some other implementation prefers prime-sized.

The advantage of power-of-two is fast bucket access. Instead of `%` operation (modulus), `&` operation (bitwise and) can be used.

The advantage of prime-sized is tolerance for not very good hash fuctions like you have.

If you can use other libraries, like `boost::unordered_map`, you can try them, to avoid dependency on the specific STL details. But better yet improve the hash function.